# Not able to geo code japanese address using google API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, reverse-geocoding

I am implementing http://jsfiddle.net/Zf6LG/ for reverse geocoding.

```
     $(function () {
     var lat = 44.88623409320778,
         lng = -87.86480712897173,
         latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
         image = 'http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue-dot.png';

     //zoomControl: true,
     //zoomControlOptions: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE,

     var mapOptions = {
         center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
         zoom: 13,
         mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
         panControl: true,
         panControlOptions: {
             position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
         },
         zoomControl: true,
         zoomControlOptions: {
             style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE,
             position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_left
         }
     },
     map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions),
         marker = new google.maps.Marker({
             position: latlng,
             map: map,
             icon: image
         });

     var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
     var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, {
         types: ["geocode"]
     });

     autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);
     var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

     google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function (event) {
         infowindow.close();
         var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
         if (place.geometry.viewport) {
             map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
         } else {
             map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
             map.setZoom(17);
         }

         moveMarker(place.name, place.geometry.location);
         $('.MapLat').val(place.geometry.location.lat());
         $('.MapLon').val(place.geometry.location.lng());
     });
     google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (event) {
         $('.MapLat').val(event.latLng.lat());
         $('.MapLon').val(event.latLng.lng());
         infowindow.close();
                 var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                 geocoder.geocode({
                     "latLng":event.latLng
                 }, function (results, status) {
                     console.log(results, status);
                     if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                         console.log(results);
                         var lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat(),
                             lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng(),
                             placeName = results[0].address_components[0].long_name,
                             latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

                         moveMarker(placeName, latlng);
                         $("#searchTextField").val(results[0].formatted_address);
                     }
                 });
     });

     function moveMarker(placeName, latlng) {
         marker.setIcon(image);
         marker.setPosition(latlng);
         infowindow.setContent(placeName);
         //infowindow.open(map, marker);
     }
 });
```

But in address field when I   enter this japanese  address "東京都新宿区市谷砂土原町３１９" (which is "Ichigayasadoharacho, Shinjuku, Tokyo, Japan") and press tab (onchange) does not change the map.

I am not able to figure out why this does not work. searching this address = "東京都新宿区市谷砂土原町３１９" in maps.google.com shows the map perfectly.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you are confusing things.  Reverse geocoding takes coordinates and returns an address.  Geocoding takes an address and returns coordinates, which are you attempting to do?

Comment: Both of those addresses geocode successfully for me: http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_example_geo2.asp?addr1=Ichigayasadoharacho,%20Shinjuku,%20Tokyo,%20Japan&geocode=1&addr2=%E6%9D%B1%E4%BA%AC%E9%83%BD%E6%96%B0%E5%AE%BF%E5%8C%BA%E5%B8%82%E8%B0%B7%E7%A0%82%E5%9C%9F%E5%8E%9F%E7%94%BA%EF%BC%93%EF%BC%91%EF%BC%99&geocode=2

Comment: Your jsfiddle is also now working for me. http://jsfiddle.net/DXkZJ/

Comment: Are you sure this addres 東京都新宿区市谷砂土原町３１９ is working in this jsfiddle? Because I just checked and it didn't work for me

Comment: No, the autocomplete is in english, only the english version worked for me (but that did work). If you want to use the japanese you need to change the language.

Comment: One more question @geocodezip . Instead of just giving latitude and longitude of suggested address(auto complete) can I get such cordinates for any such address for example I typed "Ichigayasadoharacho, Shinjuku, Tokyo, Japan" then pressed tab?